# Can I specify which version of Maven is used when deploying my Java app to the Heroku Cedar stack?

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm deploying an application that requires Maven 3.0.4 to the Heroku Cedar stack, but the build fails with this warning:

```
Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
Build with Maven 3.0.4 or later. Maven 3.0 through 3.0.3 inclusive do not pass 
correct settings.xml to Maven Release Plugin.
```

I believe that this failure is caused by this Maven bug:

- [REGRESSION: Injected Settings in a Mojo are missing the profiles from settings.xml](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5224).

Is there any way I can configure Heroku Cedar to use a different version of Maven?

Answer (score 5):

Fork the [Heroku Java Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/) git repository, then clone it.

Open **bin/compile** in your editor. Look for the following lines:

```
# install maven with base repository
MAVEN_URL="http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-jvm-langpack-java/maven.tar.gz"

if [ ! -d .maven ]; then
  echo -n "-----> Installing Maven 3.0.3..."
  curl --silent --max-time 60 --location $MAVEN_URL | tar xz
  chmod +x .maven/bin/mvn
  echo " done"
fi
```

Change the MAVEN_URL to download Maven 3.0.4 from Apache:

```
MAVEN_URL="http://www.us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz"
```

Commit your changes, then configure your Heroku Cedar instance to use your custom buildpack:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=[YOUR GITHUB REPO] --app [YOUR HEROKU CEDAR APP]
```

For details, see Heroku's instructions [Using a Custom Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do it as long as you create your own build pack. Have a look at what I did to use maven 3.0.4 at https://github.com/jtzikas/heroku-buildpack-java.

In short what I had to do, was to change the uri of the location of maven but also change the directory structure since the heroku one contains the .m2 and the .maven directory. Those directories are needed in order for the rest of the script to run.

```
# install maven without base repository
MAVEN_URL="http://www.us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz"

if [ ! -d .maven ]; then
  echo -n "-----> Installing Maven 3.0.4..."
  curl --silent --max-time 60 --location $MAVEN_URL | tar xz
  mv apache-maven-3.0.4 .maven
  mkdir .m2
  chmod +x .maven/bin/mvn
  echo " done"
fi
```

The .m2 directory is the repository location and the .maven directory is the location of the maven installation. You will need to extract the maven 3.0.4 into the .maven directory and not the apache-maven-3.0.4 that is the root of directory of maven 3.0.4. Dont forget that you need to create an empty .m2 directory to host the maven repository

Check the heroku documentation for instruction on how to use custom buildpacks.